# Wrong position of infowindow on small zoom levels. Google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

On small zoom levels one place will be displayed twice or more (world map is repeated horizontally). When I place marker on map with coordinates (e.g. -32.05604, 115.74718) I will see it on map more than once. It's normal.

But if I try to show infowindow on mouse hover I will get wrong behaviour. Infowindow will be always showed near one of my markers and never near other, without relation what marker was under mouse cursor.

See example here: (try to move mouse to left marker on map).
https://jsfiddle.net/m3wpk1gr/1/

How to show infowindow for marker which under mouse?

My code:

```
function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-32.05604, 115.74718),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 1,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-32.05604, 0)
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map
        });

    marker.setMap(map);

    var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
        iw.setContent('InfoWindow');
        iw.open(map, this);
    });
    marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
        iw.close();
    });

}

initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is nothing you can do to get the desired result(the position is correct, so when the position exists multiple times on a map, the API has to make a decision).

What you can do: set the `optimized`-option of the marker to `false`, then they will not be repeated at lower zoom-levels

Comment: Thanks, @dr-molle. So sad.